# Condense datepicker init?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

There must be a way to condense this, but I can seem to figure out the syntax for an init with multiple options set.

http://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/scypk2ao/

Basically, pre-populate a datepicker input with today's date and disallow past dates.

```
$("#event_date").datepicker();
var defaultDate = new Date();
$("#event_date").datepicker('setDate', defaultDate);
$("#event_date").datepicker('option', 'minDate', 0);
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/scypk2ao/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the working code. Thanks, J Santosh.

http://jsfiddle.net/10dw46ne/

```
$("#event_date").datepicker({
    minDate: new Date(),
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
}).datepicker('setDate', new Date());;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `setDate` isn't an option, but rather a method, you should first create the datepicker object using its constructor, and then call the method. This can be done without the two `$(..)` queries in the following way::

```
$("#event_date").datepicker({
    minDate: 0
  }).datepicker('setDate', defaultDate);
```

Comment: I tried that but for some reason it does not actually populate my #event_date element with the default date.

Comment: Yeah... still doesn't pre-populate the date field. http://jsfiddle.net/scypk2ao/1/

Comment: This code is working , check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/10dw46ne/). Just added the above code in fiddle .